# Plot gets really small after adding text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm doing some research on Eurovision and I plotted some countries' points throughout the years.
I min-max scaled every country so that points are scaled from 0 - 100 for every year.

I made an array of the countries I use `usefull = ['Ukraine', 'United Kingdom', 'Russia', 'Georgia', 'France', 'Armenia', 'Azerbaijan', 'Israel', 'Spain', 'Austria', 'Turkey']`

I then used the following code to plot and annotate on Ukraine:

```
plt.style.use("default")

# UKRAINE
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=False, figsize=(20, 10))

country = eurovision.loc[eurovision["Country"] == usefull[0]]
ax1.plot(country["Year"].astype(str), country["Scaled Grand Final Points"], label = "Ukraine", color = "#0057b7")

# ANNOTATING EVENTS
ax1.text(13.5, 50, "                      2020 \n \n No contest because of COVID-19", 
fontsize = 12, bbox=dict(facecolor='#ffd700', alpha=0.7))
ax1.text(13.5, 92, "                WON IN 2022 \n \n   A lot of sympathy votes because \n of the Russian War against Ukraine", 
fontsize = 11, bbox=dict(facecolor='#ffd700', alpha=0.7))
ax1.text(4.8, 92, "                                                WON IN 2016 \n \n                   Their song '1944' received lots of sympathy votes \n The song refers to the mass deportation of Crimean Tatars by Joseph Stalin", 
fontsize = 11, bbox=dict(facecolor='#ffd700', alpha=0.7))
ax1.text(0.05, 1.7, "                             2005 \n \n Low votes from eastern countries because \n    of the pro-European Orange Revolution", 
fontsize = 11, bbox=dict(facecolor='#ffd700', alpha=0.7))
ax1.text(4.5, 4.1, "                     2009 \n \n Low votes from eastern countries due \n          to an energy price conflict", 
fontsize = 11, bbox=dict(facecolor='#ffd700', alpha=0.7))

ax1.set_title("Ukraine")
ax1.set_xlabel("Year")
ax1.set_ylabel("Total final points")
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1, 0.1))
```

This worked out fine as it outputted a nice plot with the correct annotations.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bc4B.png

However when I tried to do the exact same thing on Spain:

```
# SPAIN
fig, ax9 = plt.subplots(1, 1, sharey=False, figsize=(20, 10))

country = eurovision.loc[eurovision["Country"] == usefull[8]]
ax9.plot(country["Year"], country["Scaled Grand Final Points"], label = "Spain", color = "#FABD00")

ax9.text(1.3, 21, "                                       1960 \n \n Random event", 
fontsize = 11, bbox=dict(facecolor='#FFF08', alpha=0.7))

ax9.set_title("Spain")
ax9.set_xlabel("Year")
ax9.set_ylabel("Total final points")
ax9.legend()
```

I get outputted a super small plot with a small annotation box.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrpeZ.png

I really thank you guys in advance for helping me finding the fix!

Comment: What are the data values for Spain?

Comment: Below you can find a screenshot of the table with only Spain
https://imgur.com/a/OPjOzIG

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, for Ukraine you have only around 14 data points from 2003 to 2022, but for Spain you have 62 data points from 1961 to 2022..

Comment: Yes! That's correct!

Comment: Wish to replicate this issue on my side, but for that I will need all the Spain and Ukraine values in text form - not image. It probably has to do with the values being plotted.

Comment: Oh yes sure! Here is a link to download the csv I use! [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/66195c369a84c1aa9b4e363cd9f7961220220528143425/2cb1da)

Comment: And I use this to min-max scale the points.
`scaled_points = []

for year in eurovision['Year'].unique():
    year_to_scale = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 100)).fit_transform(eurovision[eurovision["Year"] == year][['Grand Final Points']])
    var = year_to_scale.tolist()
    for x in var:
        for y in x:
            scaled_points.append(y)

eurovision['Scaled Grand Final Points'] = scaled_points`

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, I get a normal size plot for Spain. I am using **python 3.8.9** and **matplotlib version 3.5.1** on Mac **Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0**

[image: Spain Plot]

I notice one difference in your code for *Ukraine vs Spain* which made the text and bounding box not appear in my first attempt. You are missing `astype(str)` in your code for `ax9.plot`

```
ax9.plot(country["Year"].astype(str), country["Scaled Grand Final Points"], label = "Spain", color = "#FABD00")

# rotates the x-axis labels by 45 degrees
plt.setp(ax9.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right', fontsize='x-small')

# sets alternate labels to off
for n, label in enumerate(ax9.xaxis.get_ticklabels()):
   if n % 2 !=0:
      label.set_visible(False)
```

Once I fixed this line, I got the text in the plot - same like Ukraine.

Comment: Yes! You're a legend man! The only downside is that the years on the x-axis are very close to each other. Any fix for this?

Comment: I have updated the code to turn the x axis labels and also to show only alternate tick, so you have more space to display the remaining tick labels.